# How to install Easy Redmine on Linux+Apache environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, redmine

How can I install Easy Redmine 2016 (A Ruby on Rails based Project Management solution) on Linux+Apache environment with following specification,

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Apache
- MySQL

Comment: Hey Thanks spickermann, actually I was looking for a step by step guide like I have posted below.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Please find the appropriate StackExchange to post this. Also, it has nothing to do with _LAMP_. Downvoted.

Comment: LAMP was a typo, I meant Linux and Apache :|

Comment: Mr. Spickemann this is definitely NOT a off topic !

Answer (score -1):

## **A step by step guideline follows,**

## **# STEP 1 : Clean, Update & Upgrade your Advanced Packaging Tool of your OS**

```
 > sudo apt-get clean
 > sudo apt-get update
 > sudo apt-get upgrade
```

## **# STEP 2: Install Ruby and related stuffs**

```
 > sudo apt-get install ruby-full
 > sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
 > sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
 > sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickwand-dev

 > ALTER DATABASE <databasename> CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
 > ALTER TABLE <databasename>.easy_attendance_activities CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
 > ALTER TABLE <databasename>.easy_settings CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
 > ALTER TABLE <databasename>.easy_user_time_calendar_holidays CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

~~ Take care of this : warning /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777

## **# STEP 3 : Install Ruby gems**

```
 > sudo gem install bundler
```

## **# STEP 4: Install redmine installer gem**

```
> gem install redmine-installer
```

## **# STEP 5: Install the downloaded package of Easy Redmine**

```
> redmine install path/to/downloaded_archieve/easyredmine_2016_stable_u8824_v2018_1_1.zip
```

## # Step 6 [ Steps after successfully installing Easy Redmine... ]

- Run the folloing commands

> ```
> > sudo gem install passenger
> > sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger
> > sudo a2enmod passenger
> > sudo service apache2 restart
> ```

- Add the following to /etc/hosts file

> `127.0.0.1    local.easy-redmine.com`

- sudo gedit /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf & check everything is okay
- Edit /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/passenger.conf & add the following inside *"PassengerDefaultUser www-data"* so that it appear like,

> ```
> <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
>   PassengerDefaultUser www-data
>   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
>   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
> </IfModule>
> ```

- Add the following to the /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>    RailsEnv development
>    ServerName local.easy-redmine.com
>    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/easy_redmine/public
>
>    <Directory "/var/www/html/easy_redmine/public">
>        Options FollowSymLinks
>        Require all granted
>    </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

**[NOTE]** : Do everything (except apt-get ...) without sudo. Use chmod, chown whereever required to make the commands work without sudo.

**[NOTE]** : You may get several errors while writing the database tables related to charset.

**[NOTE]** : If If tried installing ruby or rails or redmine earlier & you wish you remove all is existances then feel free to do the following,

```
 > apt-get purge ruby
 > apt-get purge rails
 > apt-get purge redmine
 > sudo apt autoremove & additionally,
 > sudo grep -i "ruby"
 > sudo rm -rf path/to/ruby_existances
```

> **Disclaimer** : This is a draft version, will be arranged / improved further.